# Character will not move, only the scene moves

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

In Unity 2020.3.25 in 3d Mode, I have the Animator named Soldier where he is supposed to transition form Idle to Walk when you either press the arrow keys or certain letter keys.  In Edit then Project Settings the default for Horizontal is Left Arrow or Letter A to rotate left, or to rotate right is either the right arrow or letter D.  Vertical Move is the up and down arrows or letters S to move down or letter W to move up. As can be seen all the connections are to their appropriate fields.  The following is the C# code that is attached to the character.  Instead of the character transitioning from Idle to Walk, when you press the keys the entire scene moves.  The following is the C# Code.

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class TankControls : MonoBehaviour 
 {

    public GameObject thePlayer;
    public bool isMoving;   
    public float horizontalMove;  
    public float verticalMove;


    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical"))  
        {
             isMoving = true;
             thePlayer.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Walk");
             horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150;  
             verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.9f; 
             thePlayer.transform.Rotate(0, horizontalMove, 0);  
             thePlayer.transform.Translate(0, 0, verticalMove);  
        }
        else
        {
             isMoving = false;  
             thePlayer.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Idle");  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ThePlayer` public field is visible in the editor. You could check which `GameObject` is referenced there, I suspect it's a `Transform` with the `Camera` component. You could just translate or rotate the transform (without `thePlayer`. `Infront`). Even better would be to cash the transform that the `TankControls` `Monobehaviour` is attached to in an `Awake` call. Or just check which `GameObject` is attached to the `thePlayer` field.